# Custom Post Type Query multiple Taxonomy Terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

So on this Custom Post Type list page there is a list of Properties.

I have a custom search feature where they can search for Properties with certain Taxonomy Terms - but they can also search for Multiple Taxonomy Terms.

**Question**:
If someone selects 2 terms then the only Properties that should display in the list are Properties with `term_one` `AND` `term_two`

So I tried this below:

```
$required_features_slugs = array();
if( isset ( $_GET['features'] ) ) {
    $features_slugs = $_GET['features'];
}

$feature = get_terms('features');

$tmp_required = $required_features_slugs;

$property = array(
    'post_type'     => 'properties',
    'paged'         => $paged,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'features',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $tmp_required,
            'operator'  => 'AND',
        )
    ),
);
```

The URL looks like this:

```
features%5B%5D=accredited-landlord&features%5B%5D=cellarbasement
```

Now because these two Features are selected it should only return one Property because there is only one Property with `term_one` `AND` `term_two` together

However I don't get this result instead I get 4 Properties because there are 4 Properties. 3 with `term_one` and 1 with `term_two`.

What I want to happen is for 1 Property to be returned because there is only one Property with `term_once` `AND` `term_two` together.

Is there something wrong that I am doing in the Query?

**Edit**: Updated `PHP` file

```
$required_features_slugs = array();
if( isset ( $_GET['features'] ) ) {
    $required_features_slugs = $_GET['features'];
}

$all_features = get_terms('features');

if( ! empty( $required_features_slugs ) ) {
    foreach ( $all_features as $feature ) {
        $tmp_required = $required_features_slugs;

        if( ! in_array($feature->slug, $required_features_slugs) ) {
            array_push( $tmp_required, $feature->slug );
        }

        $property = array(
            'post_type'     => 'properties',
            'paged'         => $paged,
            'tax_query'         => array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'features',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $tmp_required,
                'operator'  => 'AND',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit #2**:
So here is the `var_dump` to the Query:

```
array(3) { ["post_type"]=> string(10) "properties" ["paged"]=> int(1) ["tax_query"]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "features" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "accredited-landlord" [1]=> string(14) "cellarbasement" } ["operator"]=> string(3) "AND" } }
```

And here is the `var_dump` to the terms:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "accredited-landlord" [1]=> string(14) "cellarbasement" }
```

Comment: Did you check out what the variables contain? E.g. `$required_features_slugs` and `$tmp_required` are currently empty arrays and `$features_slugs` and `$feature` are never used.

Comment: I've updated my answer hopefully that answers your question :)

Comment: `features` in `$_GET` should have brackets on end to behave as array, for example `example.com/?features[]=10&features[]=20...`

Comment: @KrzysztofGrabania they do have the `[]` there in Unicode `%5B%5D` is the `[]` in Unicode

Answer (score 3):

**Query Arguments:**

If `$input_terms` is the input array of term slugs, then you should be able to use (if I understand the question correctly):

```
$property = [
    'post_type'         => 'properties',
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'tax_query'         => [
        [
            'taxonomy'  => 'features',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $input_terms,
            'operator'  => 'AND',
        ]
    ],
];
```

where we added a missing array in the tax query.

**Validation:**

We should **validate** the input terms first.

Here are some examples:

- Check the maximum number of allowed terms:

  ```
  $valid_input_terms_max_count = count( $input_terms ) <= 4;
  ```
- Check the minimum number of allowed terms:

  ```
  $valid_input_terms_min_count = count( $input_terms ) >= 1;
  ```
- Check if they input terms slugs exists (assumes non-empty input array):

  ```
  $valid_input_terms_slugs = array_reduce( 
      (array) $input_terms, 
      function( $carry, $item ) { 
          return $carry && null !== term_exists( $item, 'features' ); 
      }, 
      true 
  );
  ```

  where we collect [`term_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_exists/) for all the terms into a single boolean value.
- We could also match the input slugs against a predefined array of slugs

**Generated SQL:**

Here's a generated SQL query for two existing term slugs in `$input_terms`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM wp_term_relationships
        WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (160,161)
        AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
    ) = 2
) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'properties' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Hope you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I didn't put enough into the question to make it understandable - I have added to the question now. All I want to do is `$_GET` the URL; check if there is `features` in the search query and if there is return result depending on that query. **However** if there are 2 terms in the query only return the Properties with both terms

Comment: As a debug step, just use  `$input_terms = [ 'term_one', 'term_two' ]` and make sure the `$property` array here above returns correct query results. What happens then? @CoderSte

Comment: So I've done a `var_dump` to make sure the query works and it seems to be correct. As for adding in the terms manually to `$input_terms` I have done that and I still get the result I am getting now with no change

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to work as expected on my vanilla install. I only get posts that are assigned to all terms in our `$input_terms` array. What does your SQL query look like? @CoderSte

Comment: By SQL Query I assume you mean the `WP_Query` for that page? If so here it is --> [Pastebin Query](http://pastebin.com/sZDV9dZv)

Comment: The SQL of the query that is fed with the $property arguments. From your dump it looks like your tax_query is not an array of arrays.  Try to copy the array structure I adjusted in my answer. @CoderSte

Comment: Yep I have just done that and sadly still no result :( - I appreciate your replies btw :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43644/discussion-between-birgire-and-coderste).

Answer (score 1):

Try change operator to `'operator'  => 'IN'`, or try use code something like this:

```
$required_features_slugs = array();
if( isset ( $_GET['features'] ) ) {
    $required_features_slugs = $_GET['features'];
}

 if( ! empty( $required_features_slugs ) ) {

 $property = array(
        'post_type'     => 'properties',
        'paged'         => $paged,
        'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        ),
  );


foreach ( $required_features_slugs as $feature ) {
        $property['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'features',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $feature,
        );
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried in `IN` `operator` and I still get the same result as before - I just tried your method really hoping it was going to work but unfortunately it did not :(

Comment: try debug final $property var: echo '<pre>'; print_r( $property ); echo '</pre>';

Comment: Yeah I managed to figure out what was wrong in the end :) Thanks for all your help @Nefro I appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
$property = array(
    'post_type'     => 'properties',
    'paged'         => $paged,
    'tax_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',    
    ),
);

$features = $_GET['features'];

foreach ($features as $feature) {
    $property['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'features',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => $feature,   
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) This one is similar to @Nefro answer so I don't think it will work

Comment: But there is no another possibility to make it work

Comment: Maybe something could be wrong with my overall Query :/

Comment: Maybe you should change `field` property in `tax_query` to `term_id` istead of `slug`?

EDIT. nvm, I see that in query URL are slugs

Comment: Do you iterate over `$_GET` or `get_terms`?